# uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, react-native, crash

My application developed in react native works fine in android, but it crashes on iOS:

```
022-05-21 16:38:24.748682+0530 parkingplace[1949:134115] -[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281911a70
2022-05-21 16:38:24.748911+0530 parkingplace[1949:134115] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281911a70'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x190d2d288 0x1a9a27744 0x190e0afc4 0x190cc1e98 0x190cc0f70 0x194078b68 0x193603050 0x193460d34 0x1932bb3b4 0x1933e5d90 0x193505aa0 0x193744764 0x1936cfd14 0x1932bc1a0 0x19337c0d8 0x1932be0a4 0x1933a8244 0x19382ce60 0x1932ec484 0x19332fcc4 0x193465b38 0x1933a6508 0x1a2f37294 0x1a2f5d090 0x1a2f18308 0x1a2f19958 0x1019027c0 0x101906264 0x1a2f19c70 0x1a2f19040 0x1a2f1d700 0x190d4f414 0x190d601a0 0x190c996f8 0x190c9f05c 0x190cb2bc8 0x1acde6374 0x193622648 0x1933a3d90 0x100c90154 0x10171dce4)
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
dyld4 config: DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/system/introspection DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES=/Developer/usr/lib/libBacktraceRecording.dylib:/Developer/usr/lib/libMainThreadChecker.dylib:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DTDDISupport.framework/libViewDebuggerSupport.dylib
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString containsObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281911a70'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a same error *(libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException)*
and I solved it
Issue was with info.plist file in my case it was a

```
<key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
```

that used twice even though it should be only once and if you need multiple strings in CFBundleTypeRole you can have a `<array> </array>` tag
**Remember** that array can only be used when their is more than one items in that otherwise you will get "Asses validation failed" at time of distributing of app on appstore
Hope it will help someone